# What is the difference between the various Gourmia GTF7900 Air Fryer cooking modes?

Tags: baking, oven, frying, broiling, air-frying

Recently I got myself a new [Gourmia GTF7900 Air Fryer](https://www.gourmia.com/item.asp?item=10324). The webpage says this oven has 14 cooking modes. It has 4 heating elements (two below and two above tray) and a hidden fan behind the side wall.

The front panel looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the menu includes only 13 selections. Where is the 14th one?

Here's the [user manual](https://www.gourmia.com/pdf/GTF7900%20-%20User%20Manual.pdf). It does not mention the technical details of what elements of the oven are used with each cooking mode. From a few cooking attempts, it looks like most of them apply both the heating elements and the fan. For example, what is the difference between the "*AIRFRY*", "*PIZZA*" and "*BAKE*" modes?

Since the heating elements are inside the main chamber, what is the difference between "*BAKING*" and "*BROILING*"?

Also, as you can see, there is a "*CONVECTION*" button there. But it is not cleat to me what is the difference between using this button and the "AIRFRY" cooking mode?

Comment: Obviously you have more than 14 modes, as any "mode" that can have convection added is two modes - one with convection and one not. Unless they only let you use it when in "bake" mode, and then that's your 14th. Probably most of the modes are pretty much the same, but claimed to be different for marketing so you'll buy this instead of a toaster-oven-airfryer with only 12 modes or 4 modes, even if the 4 modes would do everything you actually wanted to do ;-) If the fine manual doesn't enlighten you as to the details...

Comment: Conventionally, Baking is using the below the tray elements and Broiling is using the above the tray elements.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - thanks. That's what I anticipated re baking vs broiling, but AFAICT it is not so. I'll do some more rigorous testing. Maybe I missed something.